# Plagiarism? What are the requirements to Modeling/adapting published research for software development?

Tags: licensing, copyright, software-development, intellectual-property

I would like to create a suite of software tools (for commercial use) to be used by medical professionals in their daily practice. This will require that I utilize information published in medical journals.

For instance, there is a questionnaire that was validated (verified that it measures what it is intended to measure) by researchers; and the questionnaire was published in a medical journal.

In order for me to adapt it into a software tool, I will need to use the specific language that the validated questionnaire uses. If I change the language, it will invalidate the questionnaire.

My question is: What legal concerns should I have regarding the use of published research to create commercial use software? Is creating a citations page within the application that the end-user can view sufficient protection?  Do I need to seek a license or written permission even though the information is published in a journal?

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'm just wondering if it's more appropriate for the Law or Academia sites.

Comment: Although it would be appropriate on those sites, I think it is just as appropriate here as well. I think that this is just a question that requires an answer that takes information from so many different domains, we just aren't used to it. I think it's a great question, and I look forward to seeing what comes out of it

Comment: Link to Academia cross-post: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83264/52772

Comment: Link to Law cross-post: http://law.stackexchange.com/q/16422/5164

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specifically about open source software, but rather about copyright as it pertains to software generally.

Comment: IMO this is a clear-cut Law question. And, the link to the post on Law above has an accepted answer already.